# How to enable update button dynamically in angular material

Tags: angular

[image]

I have a mat-table in which I have two columns, one is of user role and second column has an update button, now what I want is whenever a user selects any option in user role dropdown list, the update button should enable. But if selected item in list is same update button should remain disabled as before.

Can any body help me out?

Here is my column details:

```
<!-- User Role Column-->
<ng-container matColumnDef="roleName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User Role </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-title="User Role:">
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="element.clientRoleId" class="table-select">
             <mat-option [value]="clientRole.clientRoleId" *ngFor="let clientRole of clientRoleList" >
              {{ clientRole.roleName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select> 
    </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Update User Role Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="updateUserRole">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Update User Role</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-title="Update User Role:"> 
        <button mat-stroked-button color="blue-strok" [disabled]="element.roleName">Update</button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

All data is coming from an api.

Comment: what did you try? do you have some more code? you will not get around keeping track for each row whether the value has been changed or not and enable/disable the button accordingly

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to store the initial `clientRoleId` of your users.

So to do it I will create a 'temp' variable to store only the `clientRoleId` values with a `map`.

```
// this array is just to simulate your data
users = [
  { clientRoleId: 1, name: "User1" },
  { clientRoleId: 2, name: "User2" },
  { clientRoleId: 1, name: "User3" }
];

tempUsers = []

ngOnInit(){
  this.tempUsers = this.users.map(obj => obj.clientRoleId)
}
```

Then on your template, the data on your original array will automatically change when you will select value on `mat-select` because of your `[(ngModel)]="element.clientRoleId"`. So the only thing to do is to checj if the new value is the same as the old one.

```
<button mat-stroked-button 
        color="blue-strok" 
        [disabled]="element.clientRoleId == tempUsers[i]"> // <- Here thanks to the 'temp' array
  Update
</button>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkhxxa?file=src/app/test/test.component.html) is a stackblitz example to show you a working proposition.

PS : If I can suggest something for your possibly next questions, providing a stackblitz minimal representation of your problem is always better for user to help you.

Comment: can we put get selected option from mat-select and compare it with element.clientRoleId instead of creating temp array

Comment: You need to have something to link your two elements - select and button. Because there is anything between them to know what is the correct value for the button. In this proposition I have made a 'temp' array with the initial values. You can also make an array with the disabled values. Another solution is to use (change) directive and to get the corresponding button with DOM, as `getElementById`. But I, personally, don't like this.